# SVN notify output to a file/data structure

Tags: svn

I am using svnnotify to send an email to stakeholders informing about the commit details. I would also like to store information about these commits ( file added, updated , revision number etc) in a file or some data structure which i can later use for report generation during deployment. I have googled but could not find any exact match. Can anyone please suggest if they have employed any such technique

Comment: `svn log -v`? (filler goes here)

Comment: works like a charm..thank you for this.. I read details of this command at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html but do you know if its possible to limit the output based on date since it shows the entire history? or may be i should use scripting to extract information based on date

Comment: Here's how to limit the output by date: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.dates